# Cannot access API call fetched in Parent component, in child component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, react-props

I cannot access the complete API call from PARENT component as props in the Child Component. Passed the fetch via props to the child component.

i.e. **props.housingData.address** will will produce data in child component, but **props.housingData.address** will not. Error message:

> error: "cannot access line of undefined."

````
```

    export default class Home extends React.Component {
    ...

    componentDidMount() { 
    
                var settings = {
                    "async": true,
                    "crossDomain": true,
                    "url": 
                    "https://realtor.p.rapidapi.com/properties/v2/list- 
                     for-rent? 
  sort=relevance&city=New%20York%20City&state_code=NY&limit=200&offset=0",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "headers": {
                        "x-rapidapi-host": "realtor.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "x-rapidapi-key": "API_KEY"
                    }
                }
        $.ajax(settings).done(response =>{
                        
         // Array to apply response iteration to
                            let dataArray = []; 
                           // 

        // **I believe issue is here**
                    for(let i = 0; i < response.properties.length; i++){
                            let data = response.properties[i]; 
                            this.setState({housingData: data}); 
                            }
            }   
        )
     }

     render() {
        let dataLoaded = this.state.housingData;        
        return ( 
            <div className="container">
                   <Grid container>


  //Conditional to ensure fetch ---> {dataLoaded && this.state ?
                        <Property 
                                housingData={this.state.housingData}
                        />
                        : <CircularProgress className="loader" />}

                        
                </Grid>                                   
            </div>
            
             )
         }

     }

     ```
     export default function Property(props){
      ...
      let propData = props.housingData
      const propertyInfo = info.slice(0,showItems).map((info,item)=>(
      <Card className={classes.root} }}>
        <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                component="img"
                alt="Contemplative Reptile"
                height="140"
                // image={propData.photos[item].href}
                image={info.img}
                title="Contemplative Reptile"
                />
                   <CardContent>
                     <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                            {info.address}
                      </Typography>
              </CardContent>
     </Card>
            ))
````

Comment: Do not render the child components until the data from api is fetched, or use appropriate checks for each key from the response.

By the way, your question title is misleading the body

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Will try to work with it again later. Also, I’m looking for a way to edit the title. First time poster here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected this issue. Had to assign the API response to an object in Parent Component (Home) before sending it to the child component. (Property)
This is addition to the conditional render set on the child component ensures all data from the api has fetched and assigned to props for use in the child component.

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  
 ... 
        $.ajax(settings).done(response=>{
            let dataArray = []; <--- // Set new empty array
            for(let i = 0; i < response.properties.length; i++){
                let obj = {};  <---- // Set Object
                obj = {...response.properties[i]}  <---- // Assigned response to object
                dataArray.push(obj);  <--- // Pushed to new array
            }
            this.setState({housingData: dataArray}); <--- // Send to state
        });
```